# Content-Type in HttpClient request not changing to 'multipart/form-data'

Tags: angularjs, multipartform-data, content-type

I've been trying to fix this problem for two days now, to no avail.  I'm just simply trying to send an image from an input element using HttpClient.  My typescript is:

```
  public onImageSubmit(input) {
    this.selectedFile = input.files[0];
    var uploadImageData = new FormData();
    uploadImageData.append('imageFile', this.selectedFile);

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2R0byI6IntcInVzZXJJZFwiOjEsXCJ1c2VybmFtZVwiOlwiZ2VvcmdlXCJ9In0.pBWSj-SWVj9FuPd3r2S5MJo7AZ62mwm-MjBKj409vUYi1YuCieh1FWm0XGISHkK2cF51Tu5fzeKEwg3rr8Ya1w'
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' // I have also tried without this
      })
    }
    
    this.http.post<Image>('http://localhost:9090/users/1/images', uploadImageData, httpOptions).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

I have a Spring web server running in the background.  I get the error 'Current request is not a multipart request' on the server.  Examining the request headers in Firefox shows that the `Content-Type` is `application/json` .  I have tried explicitly specifiying the content type in the header, as well as leaving it out and hoping the browser will do it.  Neither works.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `form-data-encoder` https://github.com/octet-stream/form-data-encoder

Alternatively, have you checked your tsconfig.json compilerOptions.target? I had a similar problem with a target of `es2020` which did not happen when the target was `es2015`. Understand that this is not an ideal solution since some dependencies may require `es2020`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32312080)